# how to change file name export table data to excel in java script?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am using follow function

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,', template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>', base64 = function(
                s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
        }, format = function(s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
                return c[p];
            })
        }
        return function(table, name) {
            if (!table.nodeType)
                table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {
                worksheet : name || 'Timesheet Report',
                table : table.innerHTML
            }
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
        }
    })()
```

it working for export data but file is download,download(1)...etc,Here I need to change file  name dynamically when button click. If any one have idea please help me thanks in advance.